# Find When Object Got DROPped in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We recently discovered that an external stage in our environment mysteriously disappeared, and don't know why. I assume someone must have run a DROP STAGE command at some point, but don't know  who could have done that or when it occurred.

I have tried searching Query History for instances of `LIKE '%drop stage%`, but not getting any hits. I would guess since that is a DDL command, Query History is the wrong place to look. Is there a way to find out when the stage was dropped?

Comment: I have heard that role management is sometimes a bit tricky in snowflake. Is it possible that the stage exists, but your role lost its privileges to the stage?

Comment: @KenHBS, no, my role has ownership of the stage and I was able to recreate it without hitting any naming conflicts. It was definitely gone. I also know that I definitely created it at one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the date when the stage was removed by querying the snowflake.account_usage.stages shared view. There is a `deleted` field associated with each object and this will be updated upon a drop/deletion of the stage.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that view existed. This tells me exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If I had a stage that was deleted, and then created a new one of the same name, would it create a new record in that view, or overwrite the record of the one that was deleted?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can always look in snowflake.account_usage.query_history and filter on query_type = 'DROP'. This view retains query history for one year.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the data in the snowflake database's account_usage schema can be delayed from 45 minutes to 3 hours. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html